# POST to a collection resource

Tags: spring-data-rest

In spring data rest if we POST to a collection resource, it would create that object. But why does it updates it(replaces completely) if the POST request json payload contains an object which is already present in db.?

Shouldn't it throw conflict exception or something similar? After all spring data rest says that POST to a collection resource would create a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Spring says ,

> Request that the resource at the URI do something with the provided entity. Often POST is used to create a new entity, but it can also be used to update an entity.

https://spring.io/understanding/REST#post

So you will need to make the @id in the request null (or remove it from the req) if you want to save it as a new record.